# concatenating two strings c++

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

im trying to stick two strings together without using + operator,also using loops to to that.the problem is after when it read two strings it couldnt print the second string and only the first string appears.
here is my code
this code is like copying two strings in one.

```
char str1[MAX];
char str2[MAX];

cout<<"Enter The first String:\n";
cin.getline(str1,MAX,'\n');
cout<<"Enter the second String:\n";
cin.getline(str2,MAX,'\n');

char str3[2*MAX];   int k=0;

for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++)
{ str3[k]=str1[i];  k++;    }
for(int j=0;j<MAX;j++)
{ str3[k]=str2[j];  k++;    }

str3[k]='\0';
cout<<endl<<"Here is the concatenated string:\n";
cout<<str3<<endl;
```

Comment: You're using c strings.  Have you considered using the c++ String class

Comment: @Will its done right now...

Comment: It's not done the c++ way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to write such code using pointers.

So I would substitute this wrong code

```
char str3[2*MAX];   int k=0;

for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++)
{ str3[k]=str1[i];  k++;    }
for(int j=0;j<MAX;j++)
{ str3[k]=str2[j];  k++;    }

str3[k]='\0';
```

for the following

```
char str3[2 * MAX];

char *p = str3;

char *q = str1;

while ( *p = *q++ ) ++p;

q = str2;

while ( *p++ = *q++ );
```

Also the same can be written using for loops. For example

```
char str3[2 * MAX];

char *p = str3;

for ( char *q = str1; *p = *q++; ++p );
for ( char *q = str2; *p++ = *q++; );
```

Comment: i havent passed this section yet dude!

Comment: @ali gholami So you have known something new today.:)

Answer (score 2):

Your code goes past the end of `str1` and `str2`, including their null terminators. Once the null terminator of `srt1` is copied, C string inside `str3` is considered complete, so `str2` part is ignored.

You need to modify the first loop to stop once it sees `'\0'` in `str1`, and copy `str2` from that point on. Do the same for the second loop. Your code adds null termination already, so the result will be correct:

```
for(int i=0;i<MAX && str1[i] != '\0';i++)
{ str3[k]=str1[i];  k++;    }
for(int j=0;j<MAX && str2[j] != '\0';j++)
{ str3[k]=str2[j];  k++;    }
```

**Note:** I am assuming that this is a learning exercise for which you are not allowed to use `std::string`.

Comment: Dang, too fast ;) Add a reference to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/ that describes why null termination is occuring for str1, str2.

Comment: AFAIK, the documentation specifies that the last element of the `char*` is always `null terminated` so `for(int i = 0; i < MAX - 1; i++)` should suffice, and is more optimized.

Comment: @Centril That would work too, but potentially it could copy more characters than you have to. For example, if user enters five characters and you copy all 50, that's 45 useless character copies. Not that it would make any difference in terms of timing, but it does not make the code look much simpler either.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, ah, yeah true - forgot that one.

Answer (score 2):

Correct code should be:-

```
char str3[2*MAX];   
int k=0;

for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
  str3[k]=str1[i];  
  k++;    
}
for(int j=0 ; str2[j] != '\0'; j++ )
{ 
   str3[k] = str2[j];  
   k++;   
}
str3[k]='\0';
```

You were not taking into account null terminator and hence reading past that.

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
for(int i=0; str1[i] ;i++) 
{ str3[k]=str1[i];  k++;    }
for(int j=0; str2[j] ;j++)
{ str3[k]=str2[j];  k++;    }
```

You have to stop concatenating when `str1` or `str2` ends that is when `str1[i]` or `str2[j]`
will be `0 ('\0')`. But you were looping through `MAX`. That's why your program produced wrong output.
Hope you understand now :)

Answer (score 0):

@dasblinkenlight explains why this doesn't work in her/his answer.

Here's yet another solution using the standard C(++) library function `strcat` defined in . See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char str1[MAX];
    char str2[MAX];

    cout << "Enter The first String:" << endl;
    cin.getline(str1, MAX);
    cout << "Enter the second String:" << endl;
    cin.getline(str2, MAX);

    char str3[2 * MAX];
    strcat(str3, str1);
    strcat(str3, str2);

    cout    << endl << "Here is the concatenated string:" << endl
            << str3 << endl;
}
```